# LiteDB Index size limit issue

Tags: c#, indexing, nosql

I use this code to insert items to the database:

```
using (var db = new LiteDatabase(dataFilePath))
{
    LiteCollection<DbEntry> collection = db.GetCollection<DbEntry>("stuff");
    collection.InsertBulk(sourceEntries.Select(Mapper.Map<DbEntry>));
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
LiteDB.LiteException: Index key must be less than 512 bytes
   at LiteDB.IndexService.AddNode(CollectionIndex index, BsonValue key, Byte level)
   at LiteDB.LiteCollection`1.Insert(T document)
   at LiteDB.LiteCollection`1.InsertBulk(IEnumerable`1 docs, Int32 buffer)
```

I do not think I have fiddled with any indexes at all in any way, but if there is a way to check it please let me know.

DbEntry looks somewhat like this (no explicit identifier):

```
public class DbEntry
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

The `dataFilePath` is different every day, sometimes it can hold 200MB of data, and this error now occurs when the file has about 1.5MB of data.

Answer (score 0):

Not very familiar with LiteDB, but a suggestion:

You did not specify the version you use. Is it the stable 1.4, or 2.0 already? There is (was?) a limit of 1 MB on each entry in 1.4. Have a look at storing items as files instead.

I'd also rather set an entry ID explicitly, by naming a field `_id` or via `[BsonId]`. Maybe LiteDB is using the whole row as ID, and choking on it as it attempts to index your table.